# How to execute a function x% of the times it is to be executed?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Use case: Live images are provided in real time and are to be viewed on the screen. To lower the CPU load, the user should be able to discard images and only show, say 10%, or 50%, of the images.

If the user choose 50%, then every other image should be shown (not 50 images in a row, and then discard 50, as that would be 50% too..)

The current code:

```
void paintImage(int everyWhatImage)
{
    showImage();
}
```

shows the image 100% of the times.

If the user supply an integer, like 1,2,3 .., meaning every one, every second, every third and so on, something familiar like this could be used:

```
void paintImage(int everyWhatImage)
{   
  if(counter % everyWhatImage)
  {
     showImage();
  }
  counter++;
}
```

However, the above algorithm don't support showing less than 50% (the '2') of the images, and so the question is, how to do that?

As this is a live streaming application, it needs to be fast.

In addition, the above code is executed in a *callback function*, so there is no knowledge of when it is to be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any given picture is either shown, or not shown. If it is not shown, then the chance of any future picture being shown should go up. If it IS shown, the chance of any future picture should go way down.

So, count up to 100. If you get on or over 100, show the picture... and subtract 100:

```
static counter(0);
if (counter >= 100) {
    showImage();
    counter -= 100;
}
counter += chance;
```

where `chance` is for example `70`, which would mean 'show 70% of the pictures'. Going through it:

- first picture: Not shown; counter is at 70.
- second picture: Shown; counter is at 40.
- third picture: Shown; counter is at 10.
- fourth picture: Not shown; counter is at 80.
- fifth picture: Shown; counter is at 50.
- sixth picture: Shown; counter is at 20.
- seventh picture: Not shown; counter is at 90.
- eighth picture: Shown; counter is at 60.
- ninth picture: Shown; counter is at 30.
- tenth picture: Shown; counter is at 0.

.. and it loops from there.

Comment: Tried it and it seemed to work perfect. Very interesting algorithm!

Answer (score 2):

Save up the given proportion in a "running balance".  Every time it reaches at least 1.00, "cash in" the savings for an image.

Choosing 27% for an example ...

```
show_count = 0.00
ratio = 0.27
while (we have more images to show) {
    show_count += ratio
    if (show_count >= 1.00) {
        show_image()
        show_count -= 1.00
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers to this question all appear to implement a counter, so I thought I would suggest a probabilistic approach. You could generate a random number between zero and one each time your function is called:

```
    random = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))
```

Then, if the random number is below the prescribed percentage of images to be shown, show the image.  Otherwise, discard it.

Comment: Have an upvote for lateral thinking. Not sure whether the result is "systematic" enough. But I like your thinking out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch.  I appreciate the feedback, and you`re right: this answer wouldn't guarantee that every other image be shown in the 50/50 use case example.